# GeoServer's "infinite loading" on new layer screen

Tags: geoserver, publishing

I deployed a GeoServer 2.10.1 version on tomcat 8.x. then I created a new connection from a Postgis database and published a layer. But, when I tried to publish a new layer, the GeoServer's stayed on the "infinite loading" screen, and   the **publish** option not work properly.

Does someone has the same problem?

[image: New Layer Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the solution!

The problem is caused by a Google-chrome's extension called "PageXray" that's an extension for discover the tecnologies used to construct websites. When I turned off the extension, the GeoServer's its working again.